# Sanctum middleware stops running Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10

**Sanctum Version
3.2.5**

**Laravel Version
10.14.1**

**PHP Version
8.1.6**

**Description**

Hi, I created new Laravel 10 app, where i wanted to create the RestAPIs.
I have created some routes in my `api.php` such as `auth/login`, `auth/register`, and `/user`.
`auth/login` and `auth/register` are working fine, meaning to say its publicly accessible so it can create new user or login user and return the access token in response which is good so far.
But the issue comes when if i put the `/user` route under `auth:sanctum` middleware then it stop the laravel application.

I'm getting `Error: read ECONNRESET`.
I debugged the middleware's but nothing is found.
I'm using postman to test my routes.
Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Step Create Routes in `api.php`

   ```
   Route::post('auth/login', [AuthController::class, 'loginUser']);

   Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('user', function (Request $request) {
       return $request->user();
   });
   ```
2. Step Create `AuthController.php.`

   ```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Models\user;
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
   use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;


   class AuthController extends Controller
   {
       // Register User
       public function registerUser(Request $request)
       {
           try {
               //code...
               $validator = Validator::make(
                   $request->all(),
                   [
                       'name' => 'required',
                       'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                       'password' => [
                           'required',
                           Password::min(8)
                               ->letters()
                               ->mixedCase()
                               ->numbers()
                               ->symbols()
                               ->uncompromised()
                       ]
                   ]
               );

               if ($validator->fails()) {
                   return response()->json([
                       'status' => 'failed',
                       'message' => 'Validation Error',
                       'errors' => $validator->errors()
                   ], 400);
               }

               $user = User::create([
                   'name' => $request->name,
                   'email' => $request->email,
                   'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
               ]);

               return response()->json([
                   'status' => 'success',
                   'message' => 'User registered successfully',
                   'token' => [
                       'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                       'token' => $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken
                   ]
               ]);
           } catch (\Throwable $th) {
               //throw $th;
               return response()->json([
                   'status' => 'failed',
                   'message' => $th->getMessage()
               ], 500);
           }
       }

       public function loginUser(Request $request)
       {
           try {
               //code...
               $validator = Validator::make(
                   $request->all(),
                   [
                       'email' => 'required|email',
                       'password' => 'required'
                   ]
               );

               if ($validator->fails()) {
                   return response()->json([
                       'status' => 'failed',
                       'message' => 'Validation Error',
                       'errors' => $validator->errors()
                   ], 400);
               }

               if (!Auth::attempt($request->all())) {
                   return response()->json([
                       'status' => 'failed',
                       'message' => 'Invalid Credentials',
                       'errors' => 'email or password wrong'
                   ], 400);
               }

               $user = Auth::user();

               return response()->json([
                   'status' => 'success',
                   'message' => 'User registered successfully',
                   'token' => [
                       'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                       'token' => $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken
                   ]
               ]);
           } catch (\Throwable $th) {
               //throw $th;
               return response()->json([
                   'status' => 'failed',
                   'message' => $th->getMessage()
               ], 500);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Step User model `User.php`

   ```
   namespace App\Models;

   // use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
   use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
   use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

   class User extends Authenticatable
   {
       use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

       /**
        * The attributes that are mass assignable.
        *
        * @var array<int, string>
        */
       protected $fillable = [
           'name',
           'email',
           'password',
       ];

       /**
        * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
        *
        * @var array<int, string>
        */
       protected $hidden = [
           'password',
           'remember_token',
       ];

       /**
        * The attributes that should be cast.
        *
        * @var array<string, string>
        */
       protected $casts = [
           'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
           'password' => 'hashed',
       ];
   }
   ```
4. Test the `auth/login` Route
   [image]
5. Test the `auth/login` Route
   [image]

Comment: What does your log file show for the error?